# Determine which permission is needed?

Tags: permissions

When I am testing my site and I run into a "permission denied" error, is there a way to determine what specific permission is needed?  Even in reviewing the stack traces in the logs and what's sent by the "civicrm report error" extension, it's not always clear and I have to dig around.

What's a good strategy for quickly tracking down the permission that's needed?

Comment: This is a good question. It's hard sometimes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this Drupal or Wordpress etc? Not saying one will have a better answer than the other just making sure we are talking about CMS permissions.

Comment: WordPress.  Not sure if it's CMS permissions or Civi permissions.